# Player Jumps but does not come back down

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Im trying to make a simple fps in unity although im currently getting an error with jumping. The player on the scene jumps but does not come back down at all.

When I hit spacebar the player disappears off the scene. What am I doing wrong with in this code?

```
public class PlayerMovement : MonoBehaviour 
{
    public float speed = 6f;
    public float gravity = 9.8f;   
    public float JumpForce = 0.01f;
    public GameObject bullet;
    public CapsuleCollider col;
    public LayerMask groundLayers;

    private Rigidbody rb;
    private CharacterController _charCont;
    private Vector3 moveDirection = Vector3.zero;

    private void Start () 
    {
        _charCont = GetComponent<CharacterController>();
        col = GetComponent<CapsuleCollider>();
    }

    private void Update()
    {
        float deltaX = Input.GetAxis("Horizontal") * speed; // Get the inputs from 
        float deltaY = Input.GetAxis("Vertical") * speed;
        var Movement = new Vector3(deltaX, 0, deltaY);
        Movement     = Vector3.ClampMagnitude(Movement, speed); // clamps speed so movement is always the same
        Movement.y   = gravity;     // sets gravity on y axis

        Movement *= Time.deltaTime; // fixes the movement so that its the same across different frame rates.
        Movement  = transform.TransformDirection(Movement);
        _charCont.Move(Movement);

        if (_charCont.isGrounded) // I believe im getting the error somewhere among these lines
            moveDirection.y ? Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Space) : 0;          
        else moveDirection.y -= gravity * Time.deltaTime;

        _charCont.Move(moveDirection);
    }
}
```

Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: Where is isGrounded from? It seems like a bool that needs to be updated.

Comment: This statement makes no sense: `moveDirection.y ? Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Space) : 0;` "If the player is moving on y, then put the value of 'was the space bar pressed' on the stack, otherwise put a 0 (then do nothing with that value)"

Answer (score 0):

How about using AddForce() in FixedUpdate() ?